# Add GMail to Ubuntu Indicator Applet

Tags: ubuntu, gmail, notifications, gnome-panel

How do I add GMail to the "Me" menu, aka the Indicator Applet, in Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only way, but I found the following at the indicator applet site.  At [this Launchpad post](http://answers.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+question/110599), they suggest following [these directions](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/gmail-notifier-puts-gmail-in-your.html) to install Gmail Notifier, which worked.  I followed the first suggestion, which consisted of:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gm-notify-maintainers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gm-notify
```

and then *System > Preferences > GMail Notifier Configuration* to enter your gmail account information.

I also wanted to remove the unused evolution section of the indicator applet menu.  I followed the advice from [How do I add/remove an entry in the Indicator Applet in Gnome?](https://superuser.com/questions/73200/remove-or-add-entry-in-indicator-applet-ubuntu-gnome) and added the file "evolution" to the directory ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist, which contained the entry:

```
/usr/share/applications/evolution.desktop
```

Finally, to restart the gnome panel with the changes I ran

```
killall gnome-panel
```

so that I didn't need to log off.

Comment: you can add multiple links by posting the extras into comments, or changing "http" to "hxxp".  high-rep users can edit those into your post for you (though if you go back to edit later you'll hit the same problem).

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It makes the answer much easier to read.

Comment: No other answers yet, so I'm marking this answer "accepted" even though it was my own contribution.  It worked for me.